# Iterating through every pixel in a shader - skipping pixels

Tags: unity, shaders, hlsl, instancing

I made the below shader to draw a mesh for every pixel on a texture, and color it with that pixel.

It iterates through the pixels, correctly drawing and coloring the mesh instances. However it skips about 10% of them. Can anyone see something wrong with the shader?

The missing ones mean some pixels on the texture are being skipped, so my `xTexLoc` and `yTexLoc` values are probably doing the math wrong.

```
   //The texture size is externally supplied in the properties because WebGL 2.0 (OpenGL ES 3.0 / #pragma target 3.0`) doesn't have `Texture2d.GetDimensions()`.
   _texSize("TextureSize", Int) = 256
        ...
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma target 3.0
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma multi_compile_instancing
        
        float _drawScale;

        int _texSize;
        sampler2D _PosColorTex;
        
        // vertex shader inputs
        struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION; // vertex position
            float4 color : COLOR;
        };

        struct v2f
        {
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION; // clip space position
            float4 color : TEXCOORD3;
        };

        v2f vert (appdata v, const uint instance_id : SV_InstanceID)
        {
            v2f o;

            //Getting each pixel loc. Cast as int to round decimals downward
            float xTexLoc = (int)((float)instance_id % (float)_texSize);
            float yTexLoc = (int)((float)instance_id / (float)_texSize);
            //Divide into normalized float 0...1
            xTexLoc = xTexLoc / (float)_texSize;
            yTexLoc = yTexLoc / (float)_texSize;
            // Offset Loc so it samples from the middle of the pixel to avoid edge behavior
            xTexLoc = xTexLoc + (1 / (2 * _texSize));
            yTexLoc = yTexLoc + (1 / (2 * _texSize));
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex + (pos_color * _drawScale);
            o.color = pos_color;
            return o;
        }
        
        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            fixed4 col = i.color;
            return col;
        }
        ENDCG
```

Comment: Texture coordinates are in the range 0-1. Do you notice anything different if you divide the instance ID to be in that range?

Comment: That was absolutely the answer. Of course now I have new issues where some of my pixels aren't getting sampled, but at least I'm at the next step!

Comment: Want to edit your question to ask for help with this next step, or post an answer below showing how you solved this problem?

Comment: I'd recommend editing your question so that it describes just your current issue, rather than the issue you don't have anymore followed by your revised attempt. If anyone is curious about the full blow-by-blow of how you got here, it's saved in the edit history automatically. Keeping the question concise and focused on one piece of code to fix makes it easier for a reader to quickly understand the issue and propose an answer to help.

Comment: Edited, thanks for the help thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The above shader works fine. However, outside the shader I was dynamically sizing the texture based on the size of a data set, using the square root rounded up. When I switched to powers of to, the issue went away- perhaps it was rounding errors, or lack of support for textures in sizes other than powers of 2.

There are many [methods for calculating a power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31997707/rounding-value-to-nearest-power-of-two), but I chose to use 2048 textures, since it can contain any data set I expect to encounter, and should be [easily supported on any (WebGL) platform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/WebGL_best_practices).